# Software Design/Modelling method and tool for games?

Tags: architecture, tools

I've heard that UML is a great modelling language for software design. However, for software, such as game, that will certainly encounter major changes during the development, I doubt that UML will work effectively.

What are the common ways or models that the game programmers used? and is there any recommended tools for game designing process?

Comment: This isn't `game-design`, but I can't think what to tag it as.

Comment: I would say more architecture, even if it doesn't exactly fit the bill. Or create a new 'software-design' tag :p

Comment: @3nixios It's not architecture, and I don't think software-design is a needed tag. (Since it's pretty much architecture)

Comment: Well it definately isn't game-design...

Answer (score 2):

My most recommended tools are **Trial and Error** ([Iterative Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development)) and **Communication/Documantation**, and the experience coming out of it.

Whether you accomplish that by using good old pen and paper or sophisticated collaborative software tools doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 2):

Real software (inc. games) changes a lot during development. UML is a very practical way to visualize and think of your design. Just use a tool that saves your UML in a textual format and save your UML, all your documentation, and your game code in a version control system. That way you can see the changes that happened to your design.

I would also like to mention rapid prototyping, as a development method to test if your design works.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not afraid to modify your UML diagrams and make new ones, UML will be a very powerful tool for designing and engineering any piece of software regardless of the frequency at which it changes.

Iterative Development was mentionned in another answer and makes heavy use of UML diagrams to express the software small parts at a time.  You basically give your team an objective for a small (2-3 weeks) iteration, make a bunch of UML to conceptualize the goals and model of your iteration then code after that.  Iterative Development strongly encourages you to modify existing artifacts such as UML diagrams.

The thing to keep in mind here is that UML is not limiting because your software changes a lot during development, but it might become limiting if you make one batch of diagrams and never change them or make new ones to better reflect your ever-changing piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

Rapid Prototyping is a great way to develop new ideas and test which ones are actually fun. It's often used in the early stages of design and is relatively inexpensive compared to implementing a large part of a game and realizing it's no good.

Many smaller teams also use Agile Development Methods such as [SCRUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29)